# How should I explain Aharonov-Bohm effect in QED?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Let me clarify my problem, we all know what [Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) is, where we treat the vector potential $A_\mu$ as a classical field.

Calculate this effect under classical quantum mechanics using wave function is easy, but how should I explain the "phase cumulation" after I quantize $A_\mu$, and calculate it by QED?

Answer (score 1):

Because E = B = 0 outside of an infinite solenoid the associated Aharanov-Bohm vector potential is unaffected by EM quantization performed in the Coulomb gauge, leaving the traditional single-particle Schrodinger / QM analysis intact.